# Need Help Detecting Version of Windows (Specifically, I can't detect my own computer being 10)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

In VS2015, I'm using a method from versionhelpers.h called "IsWindowsVersionOrGreater" that returns a boolean.

It takes three arguments: wMajorVersion, wMinorVersion, wServicePackMajor.

For Windows 7, this is: 6, 1, 0

For Windows 8, this is: 6, 2, 0

For Windows 8.1, this is: 6, 3, 0

For Windows 10, this is: 10, 0, 0

(source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx)

But when I run the following,

```
if (IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(10,0,0)) std::cout << true << std::endl;
else std::cout << false << std::endl;
```

the output I get is "false."

I upgraded to Windows 10 some time ago, so this makes me worry about the reliability of the method. If I use 6.2 (windows 8), it returns true. So it might have something to do with how I upgraded from 8 to 10, and something has not registered some where...?

Additionally, there is a method that takes no arguments and returns a boolean called: "IsWindows10OrGreater." It's said that this method is only accessible by Windows 10 users, but I don't seem to have access to it. (source:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn905474(v=vs.85).aspx)

So, question being, is there a better way to identify users who are using Windows 10? If so, how? If not, how can I fix this issue? I don't need to know if they are using 7, 8, or some other version, but I do need to know if they are using 10.

Comment: Note that early betas of Windows 10 where labeled as version "6.4" instead of the marketing name "10.0" that was latter adopted. In addition, is your program explicitly manifested to be "Windows 10 compatible"?

Comment: From Windows 8 onwards you need to target your app (through its manifest) for specific versions of Windows in order to have those reported as the current version number. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx for more information.

Comment: The console window itself may have suffered some changes, but generally has the same programatic behavior, it should not matter for most uses. Why is important to make a particular case out of Windows 10?

Comment: Unless you add a manifest to your program that indicates it is Windows 10 compatible then you won't be able to detect that you are running on Windows 10 using that method (or by `GetVersionEx`). There's another way to do it, by checking the version resource of one of the system DLLs.